# undefinded property names with object.keys and for each

Tags: javascript, node.js

My problem is that I have tried to find out the property names but it only shows undefinded or numbers..

```js
let Mitarbeiter = [
   {
        Name: 'Müller',
        Vorname: 'Max',
        Wohnort: 'München'
    },
    {
        Name: 'Jochen',
        Vorname: 'Hans',
        Wohnort: 'Braunschweig'
    },
    {
        Name: 'Patrick',
        Vorname: 'Schrandt',
        Wohnort: 'Hamburg'
    },
    {
        Name: 'Michael',
        Vorname: 'Reus',
        Wohnort: 'Hamburg'
    }
];

Object.keys(Mitarbeiter).forEach(item => {
    console.log(item)
});
```

Results:

```
0
1
2
3
```

but I want Name Vorname Wohnort.. if there is only one block like:

```
let Mitarbeiter = 
    {
        Name: 'Müller',
        Vorname: 'Max',
        Wohnort: 'München'
    };
```

it is working..

I hope you can help me :)

Comment: Mitarbeiter is an array of objects but you're just finding all the keys of the array which will be numbers as arrays are index (numbers) to value data structures. You need to first iterate the array and then print out the keys of each object in the array.

Answer (score 5):

Your outer `Mitarbeiter` is an *array*, not an object. Reference one of its members, one of the objects, instead:

```
Object.keys(Mitarbeiter[0]).forEach(key => {
  console.log(key)
});
```

```js
let Mitarbeiter = [

  {

    Name: 'Müller',
    Vorname: 'Max',
    Wohnort: 'München'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Jochen',
    Vorname: 'Hans',
    Wohnort: 'Braunschweig'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Patrick',
    Vorname: 'Schrandt',
    Wohnort: 'Hamburg'
  },
  {
    Name: 'Michael',
    Vorname: 'Reus',
    Wohnort: 'Hamburg'
  }
];

Object.keys(Mitarbeiter[0]).forEach(item => {
  console.log(item)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Mitarbeiter is an array; Array is a type of object which its keys are numbers:

```
let arr = [10,20,30]
let obj = {
  "0": 0,
  "1": 1,
  "2": 2
}

console.log(Object.keys(arr))
console.log(Object.keys(obj))
```

The output of both "arr," and "obj" are the same - because of the same data structure (implementation of an object is the base of an array).

So you can write it as an object and not an array like this:

```
    let Mitarbeiter ={
   Müller: {
        Name: 'Müller',
        Vorname: 'Max',
        Wohnort: 'München'
    },
    Jochen: {
        Name: 'Jochen',
        Vorname: 'Hans',
        Wohnort: 'Braunschweig'
    },
    Patrick: {
        Name: 'Patrick',
        Vorname: 'Schrandt',
        Wohnort: 'Hamburg'
    },
    Michael: {
        Name: 'Michael',
        Vorname: 'Reus',
        Wohnort: 'Hamburg'
    }
};
```

Or as an array and iterate it's pointer